# Loading Animation Images

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, animation

I would like to know what is the best way to show a loading animation while downloading an image.

I have an image which is loaded dynamically from an internet URL. So I have about 1/2 second before seeing my image and i think it depends of the connection. So I would like to show an animation for the user while the image is still downloading.

Tanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by using the VM (MVVM). I explain if someone have the same kind of trouble :

First I have Listbox in my view which is connected to a List in my ViewModel. What I did is connect a command to the event SelectionChanged like this :

```
<ListBox x:Name="EbookBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemTemplate}" Height="505" ItemsSource="{Binding OBooks, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
         <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadCoverCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

Then in my function Load cover, I construct the url of the cover and I create a bitmapImage. But before, I initialize a boolean to say it's loading :

```
IsLoadingCover = true;
// Create the Bitmap and save it to the caching directory
CurrentCover = new BitmapImage(new Uri(cover));
CurrentCover.DownloadCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
```

Finally when the image is download i put the loading indication to false.
And in my View, my control is only visible when IsLoadingCover is true (Bool to Visibility Converter) :

```
<control:LoadingAnimation HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,123,0,0" Visibility="{Binding IsLoadingCover,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a WindowsFormHost to hold an animated gif and show/hide the host as necessary.

```
xmlns:winFormInteg="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
xmlns:winForms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
```

```
<winFormInteg:WindowsFormsHost
     Width="15"
     Height="15"
     Name="window_lading_anim"
     Loaded="OnWindowLoaded">
     <winForms:PictureBox x:Name="pictureBoxLoading"/>
</winFormInteg:WindowsFormsHost>
```

In the OnWindowLoaded method set the animated image in the Winform host control

```
private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  pictureBoxLoading.Image = Properties.Resources.myAnimatedGif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your GUI while performing other work, like downloading an image, you should download the image asynchronously.

There are several ways to do that, e.g. with the `BackgroundWorker`class (on a separate thread) or, depending on what you use to download the image, asynchronously on the same thread (which might be a better idea).